# How to force CTreeCtrl not to scroll to the item when SelectItem function is called?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have simple CTreeCtrl on my dialog. It has only two levels of depth, something like this:

[image: Simple tree. Before selection]

Imagine that the user clicked on "Third" node so it becomes selected, then he pushing on the button that is also on the dialog and executes next code:

```
// m_tree is a dialog-based class member of CTreeCtrl type 
HTREEITEM hItem = m_tree.GetSelectedItem();
if (hItem)
{
    hItem = m_tree.GetNextSiblingItem(hItem); 
    if (hItem)
    {
        m_tree.SelectItem(hItem);
    }
}
```

After that hItem, which label is "Fourth" in my sample, becomes visible at the bottom of tree control window:

[image: Simple tree. After selection]

How can I force tree control not to scroll down to selected item? I just want to select it and that's all.

Comment: You can try calling https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcee049y.aspx EnsureVisible on the previously selected item. This might flicker though, so you may try using SetRedraw(FASLE) before making the new selection and EnsureVisible.

Comment: @VuVirt heh, I'm surprised, but it seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try calling [EnsureVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcee049y.aspx) on the previously selected item. This might flicker though, so you may try using SetRedraw(FASLE) before making the new selection and EnsureVisible.